# fluid width drop down menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm having great difficultly designing a drop down menu with pure css, that has fluid width. The examples I've found all have a fixed width top menu. As soon as I make the top menu fluid width, the drop down doesn't work. Can anyone help me complete the code? I basically have 7 menu items including a blank middle one. Over the middle one I have an absolute positioned logo.

HTML

```
<div style="position:relative;">
<a href="#"><img style="position:absolute; width:14.28%; max-height:80px; margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;left: 0;right: 0;" src="\adrenicon.jpg"/></a>

<nav>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Start Here</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Destinations</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Africa</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Europe</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">America</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
  <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
  <li>&nbsp</li>
  <li><a href="#">Activities</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Planner</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;

}


nav li {
    float: left;
    width:14.28%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}




nav li a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: hotpink;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: color 1s;
    transition: color 1s;
}


   nav li a:hover {
    color: #111;

}


nav ul li ul {

    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;

}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What's supposed to be removing the `display: none;` from `nav ul li ul`? I don't see where clicking or hovering  is supposed to make that display.

Comment: @themeparkfocus edited my answer with 3rd level of ul . let me know if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to set `overflow:visible` to the main ul ( `nav ul` )

then, because you set a width of `14.28%` on the `nav ul li` you need to set a width of `100%` to the second level of `li` ( `nav ul li ul li` ) so they don't get on top of eachoter and each stays on a separate row

and because the `li` has `float:left;` you need to set `float:left;width:100%` on the `nav ul` also.

then on hover on `li` change `display:none` to `display:block` on the second `ul`

see below snippet. let me know if it works

```css
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    background-color: #333;
    float:left;
    width:100%;

}


nav li {
    float:left;
    width:14.28%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;

    position: relative;
}




nav li a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: hotpink;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: color 1s;
    transition: color 1s;
}


   nav li a:hover {
    color: #111;

}


nav ul li ul {

    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;

}
nav ul li ul li {
  width:100%;}
  
nav ul li:hover > ul{
  display:block;
}
nav ul ul ul { 
right:-100%;
top:0
}
```

```html
<div style="position:relative;">
<a href="#"><img style="position:absolute; width:14.28%; max-height:80px; margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;left: 0;right: 0;" src="http://placehold.it/100x100.jpg"/></a>

<nav>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Start Here</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Destinations</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Africa</a>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Kenya</a></li> 
              <li><a href="#">Tanzania</a></li>
            
          </ul>
       </li>
      <li><a href="#">Europe</a>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Spain</a></li> 
              <li><a href="#">France</a></li>
            
          </ul>
       </li>
      <li><a href="#">America</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
  <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
  <li>&nbsp</li>
  <li><a href="#">Activities</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Planner</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

**Edited** also for 3rd level of `ul` .
code : `ul ul ul { right:-100%;top:0;}`

Comment: Hi Mihai,
this worked, thank you. Can I ask, so I have now added a sub menu, so Destinations - Africa now splits to Kenya and Tanzania. How do I format this sub menu so it display to the right of the drop down. Currently it displays over the top. Thanks for your help.
`code`
<nav>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Start Here</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Destinations</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Africa</a>
<ul>
      <li><a href="#">Kenya</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tanzania</a></li>
</ul> </li></ul></nav>
`code`

Comment: I don.t have acces to a pc right now but i suggest you use something like `right:-100%` on the `ul ul ul ` . i will edit my answer with a solution as soon as i can.

Comment: @themeparkfocus edited my answer with 3rd level of `ul` . let me know if it works